# Laravel 9 JWT error Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-9

I got error

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 467

#0 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(826): Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator->route('login', Array, true)
#1 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php(18): route('login')
#2 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(83): App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate->redirectTo(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#3 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(68): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->unauthenticated(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#4 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.php(42): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->authenticate(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Array)
#5 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#6 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#7 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(799): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#8 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(776): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#9 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(740): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
#10 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php(729): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#13 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#15 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#18 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#21 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#22 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors.php(62): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#28 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#29 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\public\index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#31 E:\DevThings\httpd\Apache24\htdocs\business-list\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\resources\server.php(16): require_once('E:\\DevThings\\ht...')
#32 {main}
```

I found my Solution, to remove the __construct()

my __construct()

`$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);`

thats error shown because my POST need header Authorization, i tried to set it NULL or empty,
but i dont know what the effect, if i delete those.

can anyone explain me?, or the best practice to check the header authorization is null or empty?

My Logout

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $auth = Auth::check();
        if (!$auth) {
            return response()->json([
                'is_error' => true,
                'message' => 'Token Blacklisted',
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'is_error' => false,
            'message' => 'Token Success',
        ]);

    }
```

Full Code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Models\User;
use Validator;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'register']]);
    }
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'is_error' => true,
                'message' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        
        $token = Auth::attempt($credentials);
        if (!$token) {
            return response()->json([
                'is_error' => true,
                'message' => 'Unauthorized',
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();
        return response()->json([
            'is_error' => false,
            'user' => $user,
            'authorisation' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'type' => 'bearer',
            ]
        ]);

    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([
                'is_error' => true,
                'message' => $validator->errors()], 422);
        }

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);
        $token = Auth::login($user);

        return response()->json([
            'is_error' => false,
            'message' => 'User created successfully',
            'user' => $user,
            'Auth' => [
                'token' => $token,
                'type' => 'bearer',
            ]
        ]);

    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        $auth = Auth::check();
        if (!$auth) {
            return response()->json([
                'is_error' => true,
                'message' => 'Token Blacklisted',
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'is_error' => false,
            'message' => 'Success',
        ]);


        //
    }

    public function refresh()
    {
        $auth = Auth::check();
        if (!$auth) {
            return response()->json([
                'is_error' => true,
                'message' => 'Token Blacklisted',
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'is_error' => false,
            'user' => Auth::user(),
            'authorisation' => [
                'token' => Auth::refresh(),
                'type' => 'bearer',
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

My Routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'api',
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function ($router) {
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::post('/refresh', [AuthController::class, 'refresh']);
    // Route::get('/user-profile', [AuthController::class, 'userProfile']);
});

----TEST----
// Route::controller(AuthController::class)->group(function () {
//     Route::post("login", "login");
//     Route::post("register", "register");
//     Route::post("logout", "logout");
//     Route::post("refresh", "refresh");
// });
----END TEST----
```

can anyone explain me?, or the best practice to check the header authorization is null or empty?

I already tried

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```